# Accessing Bitlocker Recovery information from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

So I am trying to access bitlocker recovery information from AD using C#. I've checked out these links:

- [How to access bitlocker recovery tab programmatically to backup recovery passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075310/how-to-access-bitlocker-recovery-tab-programmatically-to-backup-recovery-passwor)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/70803ee5-bb6b-4b27-a23a-51b4a77805fb/

And they both suggest (ultimately) an implementationlike this:

```
 public String GetBitlockerKey(string compName)
    {
        string bitlockerPassword = string.Empty;
        DirectoryEntry deEntry = new DirectoryEntry(_path);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;

        try
        {
            searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=Computer)(cn={0}))", compName);
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
            object recoveryInformation = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["msFVE-RecoveryInformation"].Value;

            if (recoveryInformation != null)
            {
              // Do stuff with recovery information...
            }
            else
            {
                bitlockerPassword = "Failed to find the computer object.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle execptions
            return e.Message;
        }
        return bitlockerPassword;
    }
```

...but that property doesn't exist- the "msFVE-RecoveryInformation" property. Am I thinking about this wrong? I don't think it's a permissions issue, because I can access the bitlocker keys through AD. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do any properties exist with that method? For instance...can you get `DisplayName` instead of `msFVE-RecoveryInformation`?

Comment: yes- I get a list of properties - 37 in fact- but not the msFVE-RecoveryInformation property, and actually not the "DisplayName" property either.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `distinguishedName`. ;) Did you confirm that you have Control_Access permission as explained here? http://blogs.technet.com/b/craigf/archive/2011/01/26/delegating-access-in-ad-to-bitlocker-recovery-information.aspx

Comment: Ah, yes the "distinguishedName" property is there- and I am now confirming the Control_Access permission, but if I had to venture a guess, that is probably the issue.

Comment: Well, we ended up solving the issue described in the link you have, and this is allowing us to run a VB script that accesses the msFVE-RecoveryInformation property, (only as admin) but we still cannot access it using the C# code in my original post, even when it's put in a console app that we run as admin. the msFVE-RecoveryInformation property still doesn't exist from our C# code's perspective. Any idea why?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just completed my own C# script for the purpose of retrieving Bitlocker recovery ID and Keys. I think I see what you're missing.

My steps:

1) Connect and find the Hostname in Active Directory (in your case compName)

2) Take the FindOne() result and do another Active Directory search with the SearchRoot set as the result.path.

```
var Result = directorySearcher.FindOne();

    var Rpath = Result.Path;
    var BTsearch = new DirectorySearcher(Rpath)
    {
        SearchRoot = Result.GetDirectoryEntry(), //without this line we get every entry in AD.
        Filter = "(&(objectClass=msFVE-RecoveryInformation))"
    };
```

3) From there you can specify the recovery information you are looking for and pull up other properties.

My full script for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public class AD
{
    public AD()
    {
        ActiveDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + 
    Environment.UserDomainName);
    }

public DirectoryEntry ActiveDirectory { get; private set; }

public ADbitLock GetBitLocker(string hostname)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();

        DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(ActiveDirectory);
        directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectCategory=computer)(cn=" + hostname + "))";

        var Result = directorySearcher.FindOne();

        var Rpath = Result.Path;
        var BTsearch = new DirectorySearcher(Rpath)
        {
            SearchRoot = Result.GetDirectoryEntry(), //without this line we get every entry in AD.
            Filter = "(&(objectClass=msFVE-RecoveryInformation))"
        };

        BTsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msfve-recoveryguid");
        BTsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msfve-recoverypassword");

        var GetAll = BTsearch.FindAll();

        var BT = new ADbitLock(hostname);

        foreach (SearchResult item in GetAll)
        {
            if (item.Properties.Contains("msfve-recoveryguid") && item.Properties.Contains("msfve-recoverypassword"))
            {
                var pid = (byte[])item.Properties["msfve-recoveryguid"][0];
                var rky = item.Properties["msfve-recoverypassword"][0].ToString();

                    BT.AddKey(pid, rky);
                var lnth = BT.RecoveryKey.Count - 1;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Added... " + BT.PasswordID[lnth] + " for: " + BT.RecoveryKey[lnth]);
            }
        }

        return BT;


    }
}

public class ADbitLock
{
    public ADbitLock(string HostName)
    {
        SystemName = HostName;
        PasswordID = new List<string>();
        RecoveryKey = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddKey(byte[] ID, string Key)
    {
        PasswordID.Add(ConvertID(ID));
        RecoveryKey.Add(Key);
    }

    private string ConvertID(byte[] id)
    {
        return
          id[3].ToString("X02") + id[2].ToString("X02")
        + id[1].ToString("X02") + id[0].ToString("X02") + "-"
        + id[5].ToString("X02") + id[4].ToString("X02") + "-"
        + id[7].ToString("X02") + id[6].ToString("X02") + "-"
        + id[8].ToString("X02") + id[9].ToString("X02") + "-"
        + id[10].ToString("X02") + id[11].ToString("X02")
        + id[12].ToString("X02") + id[13].ToString("X02")
        + id[14].ToString("X02") + id[15].ToString("X02")
            ;
    }

    public string SystemName { get; private set; }
    public List<string> PasswordID { get; private set; }
    public List<string> RecoveryKey { get; private set; }
}
```

Edit: As commented below by Barry, If you don't have permissions to access bit-locker recovery keys then the findAll search returns a 0 count.

Comment: Well, I asked this question 5 years ago, and I no longer work at the company that needed this script. Thanks for taking the time to answer the question! If someone can verify your answer I'll mark at as the official answer.

Comment: Yeah some of these questions sit around so long but they're all I find when I'm searching for an answer myself. If nothing else it should help anyone else who's searching around.

Comment: God bless stackoverflow, and God bless JSWulf--I didn't have to search long for this solution, but I expected it to be a lot harder to find. A couple of notes: if you DON'T have permissions, FindAll will still return a result, with a Count = 0; and, I extracted all the timestamps from item.Path (after CN=) since the key we're looking for is the one with the latest timestamp.

Comment: Nice catch. I updated with a comment on the 0 count if you don't have permissions -- something I had noticed when others tried to look up bitlocker keys and didn't use the correct account with access. Now I can go update it with a no-permissions message.