# Access Bitlocker recovery info from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am finding links to recover bitlocker passwords from active directory using vbscript, but I would like to do this using my c# program.

I have found some information on this, but nothing has been successful so far.  Can anyone help out and correct the code, or point me in the direction of solving this?

here is the latest code that I have found and tested, but it doesn't work

```
class BitlockerModel
{
    public string RecoveryGuid { get; set; }
    public string RecoveryPassword { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }

    public BitlockerModel()
    {
        RecoveryGuid = string.Empty;
        RecoveryPassword = string.Empty;
        Date = string.Empty;
        Time = string.Empty;
    }
}

private void btnBitlockerSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var computerName = txtBitlockerSearch.Text;
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(computerName)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Computername can't be empty");
                return;
            }
            var bitlockerObject = new BitlockerLookup();
            var result = bitlockerObject.GetBitlockerInfo(computerName).ToList();

            foreach (var items in result)
            {
                lsBitlockerInformation.Items.Add(string.Format("Date: {0}", items.Date));
                lsBitlockerInformation.Items.Add(string.Format("Time: {0}", items.Time));
                lsBitlockerInformation.Items.Add(string.Format("RecoveryGUID: {0}", items.RecoveryGuid));
                lsBitlockerInformation.Items.Add(string.Format("Recovery Password: {0}", items.RecoveryPassword));
                lsBitlockerInformation.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Enter a Valid ComputerName");
        }
    }

 internal class BitlockerLookup
{
    public List<BitlockerModel> GetBitlockerInfo(string computerName)
    {
        var returnRecoveryInfo = LookupBitlockerRecoveryInfor(computerName);
        return returnRecoveryInfo;
    }
    private static List<BitlockerModel> LookupBitlockerRecoveryInfor(string computerName)
    {    
        var bitlockerModelList = new List<BitlockerModel>();

        var dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher
        {
            Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=Computer)(cn={0}))", computerName)
        };

        try
        {
            var srResult = dsSearcher.FindOne();
            if (srResult == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Failed to find the computer object.", @"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                var objValue = Marshal.BindToMoniker(srResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Path.Replace("GC://", "LDAP://"));
                var tType = objValue.GetType();
                tType.InvokeMember("Filter",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null,
                    objValue, new Object[] {"msFVE-RecoveryInformation"});

                foreach (var obj in (IEnumerable) objValue)
                {
                    var tempList = new BitlockerModel();
                    var gRecoveryGuid =
                        new Guid(
                            (Byte[])
                                obj.GetType()
                                    .InvokeMember("msFVE-RecoveryGuid",
                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty |
                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, obj, null, null, null, null));
                    var name =
                        obj.GetType()
                            .InvokeMember("name",
                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, obj, null, null, null, null)
                            .ToString();
                    var date = name.Substring(3, name.IndexOf("T", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) - 3);
                    var objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                    date = string.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", objDate);

                    var time = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("T", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1,
                        name.IndexOf("{", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) - 20);
                    var objTime = DateTime.Parse(time).ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
                    time = objTime;

                    tempList.Time = time;
                    tempList.Date = date;
                    tempList.RecoveryGuid = "{" + gRecoveryGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
                    tempList.RecoveryPassword =
                        obj.GetType()
                            .InvokeMember("msFVE-RecoveryPassword",
                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, obj, null, null, null, null)
                            .ToString();

                    bitlockerModelList.Add(tempList);
                }
                return bitlockerModelList;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Error, you must enter a computer name");
            return null;
        }

        return new List<BitlockerModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive an exception? If so, on what line?

Comment: I don't get an exception, but it doesn't return the bitlocker info that I confirmed in AD, I also was able to pull the info using the VBscript I found on the microsoft forums

Comment: I set some breakpoints in the foreach loop and it never hits 'guid' or 'password'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the beginning code worked fine, although I had to build a model to hold the responses and run the application using an administrator account

Comment: Way to go. Want to post the working code for future reference?

Comment: I answered a similar thread with a code snippet over here if its any help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571483/accessing-bitlocker-recovery-information-from-active-directory/48934703#48934703